# Copying data in pointers

Tags: c, pointers

How does one copy the data that is pointed to by another pointer?

I have the following

```
void *startgpswatchdog(void *ptr)
{
    GPSLocation *destination;
    *destination = (GPSLocation *) ptr;
```

Will this do this correctly?

I free the data that is passed into thread after passing it, so I need to copy the data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to copy data you should allocate new memory via `malloc`, then copy your memory via `memcpy`.

```
void *startgpswatchdog(void *ptr)
{
    GPSLocation *destination = malloc(sizeof(GPSLocation));
    memcpy(destination, ptr, sizeof(GPSLocation));
}
```

Comment: +1: however, answer should clarify that the OP's code causes UB because `destination` is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: What if I just want to point to the GPSLocation when creating another thread after doing the copy mentioned above?

Comment: For just pointing to same memory use `GPSLocation *destination = (GPSLocation *) ptr;`. But be careful, because if you modify this memory via the pointer, the original one will be modified too.

Comment: Thanks. I dont do modifying. I first need to copy a passed in pointers data and then I must pass around the pointer to other threads. The only reason I do this GPSLocation *destination;
    *destination = (GPSLocation *) ptr;
 is to avoid using the void ptr passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if the pointer you ae copying to actually points at something:

```
void *startgpswatchdog(void *ptr)
{
    GPSLocation *destination = malloc( sizeof( GPSLocation ) );
    *destination = * (GPSLocation *) ptr;
}
```

or perhaps better:

```
void *startgpswatchdog(void *ptr)
{
    GPSLocation destination;
    destination = * (GPSLocation *) ptr;
}
```

Comment: @Oli Well, neither does the first!

Answer (score 0):

you need to allocate memory before you assign to the address pointed by the pointer.
why do you need a pointer here ? why not use

```
void *startgpswatchdog(void *ptr)
{
GPSLocation destination;
destination = (GPSLocation) *ptr;
}
```

and later if you need this variable address just use

```
&destination
```

just dont forget its a local variable :)

Comment: Because I pass the pointer to another thread I create as the (void *ptr) argument

Comment: i mean the local var - "destination".